# How to use app.use('/my/api', handlers);

Tags: express

I have a Nodejs with Express server and React (create react app) for a movie search app.

When I try to sign in or signup - I keep getting 404 not found with this http://localhost:5000/signin or http://localhost:5000/signup.

I belive I have the routes set up correctly.

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const { signin, signup, verifiEmail, resendVerification } = require('../controllers/authController');
const { resetPassword, verifyResetPassword, resetPasswordNew } = require('../controllers/resetPasswordController');
const passportService = require('../services/passport');

const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });
const requireSignin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });

const router = express.Router();
  router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({ msg: 'Auth route works' }));
  router.post('/signup', signup);
  router.post('/signup/verify-email', verifiEmail);
  router.post('/resend-verify-code', resendVerification);
  router.post('/signin', requireSignin, signin);
  router.post('/reset-password', resetPassword);
  router.post('/reset-password/verify', verifyResetPassword);
  router.post('/reset-password/new', resetPasswordNew);

module.exports = router;
```

Correct me if I'm wrong here...

I believe the problem is I can't quite figure out how to setup my  Express server correctly?

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
// const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const compression = require('compression');

const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');

// Express app init
const app = express();
// const server = http.createServer(app); // added

// Connect MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

// const server = http.createServer(app); // custom location

// middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(compression());
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: '*/*' })); // Send JSON responses
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // Parses urlencoded bodies

// router(app); // default

// Use Routes
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', index.html));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

The app works if I uncomment router(app) above and add the require statement for the routes, which were configure differently (no Router).

I want to use `app.use('/my/router', handlers);` INSTEAD of `router(app)` but can't seem to get anything to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your auth routes are defined via this:

```
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
```

Then, the URL you would reach them with is:

```
/api/auth/signup
/api/auth/signin
```

If, as in your question, you want `/signup` and `/signin` to work, then you need to change the registration of your route to:

```
app.use(authRoutes);
```

So there is no added path prefix in front.

Either change the URLs you use or change the route definitions to match the URLs you want to use.  The two just have to match.

Comment: @jfriendoo, so I just need to add /signin to app.use('/api/auth/sigin', authRoutes); - I tried it but I still get the same error.

Comment: @user3125823 - No, that's not it at all.  Please read my answer again.  If you want the URL `/signin` to work, then use `app.use(authRoutes)` with no path prefix at all on the router registration.  What URL to you want to work?  If showed you how to make the URL `/signin` work and I've shown you how to make the URL `/api/auth/singin`.  You have to decide which you want and then just follow the directions to implement that.  Right now you  have half of one and half of the other implemented which is why neither works.

Comment: @jfriendoo - read again and success! so if I want to add search routes, I would do the same thing, another app.use(searchRoutes) with search url definitions too?

Comment: @user3125823 - Yes, if you want them all the top level with no path prefix.

Comment: @jfriendoo - how would I do it with a path prefix?

Comment: @user3125823 - I kind of feel like you aren't reading either my answer or the Express documentation.  Paths with middleware and routers are additive.  If you put a path on `app.use('/somePath', someRouter)`, then `/somePath` will be combined with whatever path you use in the router.  So, if you have `someRouter.get('/login', ...)` in the router, then you would combine `/somePath` with `/login` and your route would only match `/somePath/login`.  So, if a whole bunch of routes have the same common path prefix, then you can put that prefix one place on the `app.use()` and not in the router.

Comment: @jfriendoo - yes, you are correct, I was in a bit of a rush and was just trying to get stuff to work before I had to leave. I just re-read your answer again and now understand what you were saying about the prefix - thank you again!